# Get-ChildItem Cannot Find Path Because It Does Not Exist - why?

Tags: powershell, cmd

Can anyone explain me why during the activating the order by

```
system( "start powershell  \"get-Childitem -Path \'D:\aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa\aaaaaa`
aaaaaaaaaa a aaaaaaaaa\aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa\Pliki JPG PDF\aaaaaaaaa\2019\`
19-W-D-0807\\Metal' -recurse -filter *.jpg| copy-item -Destination C:\Darek\"")
```

An error turns up that the path wasn't found and when I just turn on the console from menu start and copy this order then everything works an copies files? How to fix it so it could work without any problem?

Answer (score 0):

Without the FullName, none of the files will have the fullpath with filenames to get copied to the destination because the copy expects a full path with filename unless wildcard is specified. 
Change your code to the below one and run it in Powershell_ISE. Pipe can be used as line separator as well it can continue to the next command mentioned in the pipeline object or you can use backtick too.

```
Get-Childitem -Path 'D:\aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa\aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa a aaaaaaaaa\aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa\Pliki JPG PDF\aaaaaaaaa\2019\19-W-D-0807\\Metal' -recurse -filter *.jpg |
Select -ExpandProperty FullName |
Copy-Item -Destination C:\Darek\
```

Once this runs properly, you can wrap it to run in cmd as `start Powershell.exe .....`

PS: I am unsure that you mentioned folders are having those many "aaaa..". Also give the space wherever required in the folder names.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @FinFortune: Cause your path is ofcourse not valid.. What are those "aaaas"? Try with a proper naming convention of folder structure and check it